# UIActionSheet/UIAlertController multiline text

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

This is the code I am writing to display `UIActionSheet`.

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"updateresponseforrecurring", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                   NSLocalizedString(@"updateresponseonlyforthis", nil),
                   NSLocalizedString(@"updateresponseforallactivities", nil),
                   nil];
    actionSheet.tag = 2;
    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

This is what I get using this :

[image]

Clearly, second option is longer and thus the size gets smaller to accommodate the width.
But I want the same font size for all the options which leaves me with multiline. Also tried with `UIAlertController` but not able to set multiline text.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to work in iOS 10 and Swift 3.1:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
```

Comment: You can also set numberOfLines to 0. This allows as many lines as necessary.

Comment: This sets numberOfLines = 2 for all UIAlertControllers... What if I just want to use this for only one specific UIAlertController?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                              message: "you message go here",
                              preferredStyle: 
UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                 style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: 
[UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 0

UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: 
[UIAlertController.self]).lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the standard `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertView`.
I would recommend you to make it shorter. Why don't you make an alert and type something like this:

> Do you want to update the response only for this instance or for all
>   activities in this series.

The answers would be these:

> - Only this instance
> - All activities

Comment: If my answer did help you to solve your problem, please select it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10:

If you want to apply it to all UIAlertController, you can use these lines of code:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setNumberOfLines:2];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0]];
```

put this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the AppDelegate.